# Stop a recalculation on Excel custom function

Tags: excel, office-js

I have an Excel Custom Function that loads data from a Rest Api.
The users have big Excel files where they use these functions to retrieve information and use the results in other calculations.
Often this creates a high number of cells to be recalculated, and executes a lot of Rest Requests, resulting in a low performance of the Excel sheet and frustrating the user.

Is there any possibility to **stop the request** to the API and tell excel that the **value should not be changed**?

Comment: Yep, there is. You can store some data in memory and recall it everytime the function goes to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. This is happening at the moment, we have some sort of cache. But it would be nicer to be able to stop the calculation and not triggering a change on the cell as well.

Comment: You could turn Calculation mode to Manual or query a particular cell for a value - if value is not present exit the function. Then it's a case of training the users how to use the workbook effectively. You could even give them a big button to call the API on demand. You haven't really given us much information to work with

Comment: @erbg you can’t stop a single set of cells from calculating unless it contains a value.

Comment: @CHill60: Turning off Calculation for the hole Excel sheet is something difficult to communicate, or is there a way to turn it off for the single formula cell?

Comment: @Skin What does it mean: "unless it contains a value"?

Comment: Calculation mode is an Application wide setting, not at Cell level and not at Sheet level (although you can force a Sheet to calculate). You could turn it off when you open your Workbook (with VBA) ensuring that you turn it on again before closing in e.g. `Workbook.BeforeClose`. Alternatively have a line in your code that calls the API that checks the value of a specific (preferably named) cell and if it is set to something that indicates "off" just exit the Sub without calling the API

Comment: @CHill60 If i do this "Alternatively have a line in your code that calls the API that checks the value of a specific (preferably named) cell and if it is set to something that indicates "off" just exit the Sub without calling the API", my previous value is lost, the cell will show #value error.
This is exactly the question i was asking, can i exit the function without loosing the previous value?

Comment: @erbg - perhaps if you shared your code we could be more helpful? And how you call it?